# Definition of security incident

Tags: incident-response, incident-analysis

What's a security incident in information security?
Can an unsuccessful attack (blocked by an IPS for instance) or an attack without real impact (a port scan for instance) be considered a security incident?

Comment: What's the context? Are you creating a report for the VP, answering a homework question, determining when to activate your emergency response team?

Comment: You define what an incident is for your organization. It's all about the risks and the level of protection you require.

Comment: Absolutely anything event that may have negatively impacted the security of an organisation can be considered a "security incident".

Comment: @Neil Smithline
I would like to know when i should activate the procedures and the methodology related to incident response.

Comment: Consider this: a port scan on an externally facing machine is so common, that I would not consider it an incident in my organization. But a port scan on an internal server would. A port scan on an external machine from an IP block that should have been banned by the perimeter firewall suddenly *is* an incident. You need to define your terms for your organization.

Comment: @schroeder, thanks for your answer. So once something has been identified as an incident according to the definition in my organization, then i must start incident response procedures, right?

Comment: again, that depends on your policy - if you say that you launch IR when you deem something to be an incident, then you must, or explain why you didn't

Comment: Schroeder is correct. To be clear, a good IR policy doesn't just state *what* has to be done, but also defines the circumstances in which actions should be applied, who needs to be notified, the timeframes of each step, and also explains *why* each of these are important. This gives a context for the person applying the IR policy, so that improvisations can be made should something unusual arise.

Comment: As an example: the IR steps for someone accidentally leaking their AD password over Skype are completely different to the IR steps for a malware outbreak or a physical breach, and they are also different to a breach of PCI infrastructure or a leak of customer data. Certain things need to be reported to regulatory bodies, certain breaches require customers to be notified, certain events require C-level staff to be appraised. A major goal of an IR policy is to define the meaning of "security incident" in the context of the company's different infrastructure segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, to you as a member of an organization, a security incident is defined by your organization's security policy; it's not just "your personal opinion on what's risky" or "any event that puts the organization at risk".  Check with your organization, read their security policy, and follow its guidance.

If they don't have such a policy, and you're asking this question, that's a sign they may need one.

In the absence of a policy, you should consider it from your own point of view.  If you found a vulnerability, or possible evidence of an attack, you should document it and report it to your supervisor as quickly as possible.  It's the job of management to decide what's risky and what isn't, not you.  If you don't report it, and the problem turns out to be serious enough to involve the courts, there will be a lawsuit.  The first two things the lawyers are going to want to know is "who knew about this, and when did they know about it?"  If they find you learned about the incident but didn't report it, the legal mess could ruin you.

And once you've reported it upwards, you've discharged your duty.  If they decide not to act on it, that's their decision; even if it seems foolish or risky to you for them to ignore it.  Just make sure you've documented the incident so that people can understand you did what was reasonable given the circumstances you were in, and informed the correct person or people.

The same goes if you're a supervisor or manager, and an employee informs you of a risky or dangerous situation.  You need to report it as per your organization's security policy, or report it upwards if you don't have one.